# How to fix White Screen in Production Android APK

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

Using ionic version 4 to build an android app , while building developer mode the app is working fine on android device. When deploying in --prod --release mode the app shows white screen after splashscreen. Followed playstore publish methods by generating keystore and zipalign no luck.

On the same application as PWA release , can see a chrome console says Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)- cordova.js

```
ionic CLI : 4.12.0
ionic Framework : ionic-angular 3.9.2
ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3

Cordova CLI : 8.1.1
Cordova Platforms : Android 7.1.4
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33893227/5350407 - still remains

Comment: please attached your device with system and open chrome://inspect on browser and allow permissions and it will show error logs on console

Comment: run this and see what version it is showing: npm info cordova-plugin-ionic-webview version

Comment: Version shows 4.0.1

Comment: @sunielkalwani while inspect to execute ionic cordova run android --prod --release it shows keystore file missing and use -- --keystore keyword . when using -- --keystore <filename> , it shows it was not the part of the project

Comment: @Ananth check this link https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/problem-building-for-android-white-screen-after-splashscreen/137009/2

Answer (score 1):

i've tried so many solutions online nothing works for me
so i downgrade my typescript 2.6.2 and it works fine